# Circumvent WP CLI Command

Tags: plugins, wp-cli

I am writing a maintenance mode plugin for my multisite setup. At its core its a very simple script that returns a maintenance mode page when a option is set.
Now, I want to add cli commands to enable or disable it, but here's the catch:

When maintenance mode is enabled, any cli command just returns the html of the maintenance page.

Is there a way to circumvent this, by checking if the request came from cli or something?

In CLI it's possible to exclude plugins when executing a command, but that wont work as I need to disable the plugin which has the commands registered...

Comment: "When maintenance mode is enabled, any cli command just returns the html of the maintenance page." sounds like your maintenance logic is kicking in too soon.

Comment: Good point! Its hooked in init. What hook would you suggest using in stead?

Comment: Have you checked which hooks other maintenance plugins use? `init` sounds way too early. I'd look up the order of which they are fired, `template_redirect` comes to mind as it is quite late but before any of the contents are loaded/displayed.

Answer (score 0):

@kero the `init` hook proved to be way to early, thanks for the bright mind!

The `template_redirect` hook works just fine as you mentioned.